# How do I move a substring to the end of the string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
// "move [Personal] to end of string
       this.target.name?.replace(/^(.*)( [Personal])(.*)$/gs, "$1$3$2");
```

I'm trying to make sure " [Personal]" is at the end of the string using a vue `@keyup` handler.

But it doesn't seem to do anything other than slow the typing.

Comment: shouldn't it be `.value` instead of `.name`? also, how do you expect someone to type at the cursor when everythign moves around at each key press?

Comment: no. `this.target` is a vue object with a property. `{ name: 'foo [Personal] bar' }`

Comment: Are you reassigning the result of `replace` to any variable?  `replace` does not change a value in place, but returns a new value.

Comment: Nope, that was it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer you take a look at `.setSelectionRange` method ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)). That method allows the input box to select a few text base on the number of selections in the input value. To move the typing cursor 11 characters at left, you can try it with `.setSelectionRange(input.value.length - 11, input.value.length - 11)`. Full Example :

```js
let endText = ' [Personal]';

let input = document.getElementById('mytext');
input.onkeyup = function() {
  if(input.value.length < endText.length) { 
    input.value += endText;
  } else {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, endText.length * -1) + endText;
  }
  let targetCursor = input.value.length - endText.length;
  input.setSelectionRange(targetCursor, targetCursor);
}
```

```html
<input id="mytext" type="text" />
```